# Unable to fetch from firestore database

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fetch

When I fetch data from firestore database, it returns nothing. I think it's because I didn't include the firebase configuration in my exported Recipes class. But I don't know how to fix it/ where to inject the code. I'm using Reactjs. When I console.log(db.collection("recipe")) or when I get the snapshot I couldn't find any data. Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import RecipeList from "../components/RecipeList";
import Search from "../components/Search";
import { recipeData } from "../data/recipe_data";

import firebase from "firebase/app";
// calling firebase utility library belongs to firebase/app
import "firebase/firestore";
// need storage for database

const config = {
  apiKey: "xxxx",
  authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  appId: "xxx",
  measurementId: "xxx",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const db = firebase.firestore();

db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

export default class Recipe extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  state = {
    recipes: [],
    search: "",
  };
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      search: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(db.collection("recipes"));
    db.collection("recipes")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          let recipe = doc.data();
          recipe.key = doc;
          this.setState({ recipes: this.state.recipes.concat(recipe) });
        });
      });
    console.log(this.state.recipes);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Search
          search={this.state.search}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        />
        <RecipeList recipes={this.state.recipes} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your Firestore Document structure.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not handling your data with your react state correctly which reports null. If you console log the `.data()` retrieved per snapshot, you should see your database data being printed.

This may be related to the fact you are passing on the snapshot as the key rather than the snapshot's id name, which in most situations is not iterable for lists.

```
snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          let recipe = doc.data();
          recipe.key = doc.id;
          console.log("Recipe: " + doc.id, recipe);
          this.setState({ recipes: this.state.recipes.concat(recipe) });
        });
```

Make sure the spelling and case are also correct in the collection path.